How to log in with user SYSDBA on a Firebird database that has the role SYSDBA
I need help bypassing Firebird 2.5 error. The error is

Your login SYSDBA is same as one of the SQL role name. Ask your
database administrator to set up a valid Firebird login.
[SQLState:28000, ISC error code:335544745]

The old administrator, who is long gone, left us this database which we need to access, but it's locked because of that role error. I need to connect to it, so I can export the data, but every tool that can export the data requires for me to connect to it and I can't connect because of that error.

So an actual solution if anyone really encounters this problem.

What you first need to do is do some actual digging to find the username that was used in the database. Open the .FDB file in notepad++ and search the in places where the tables are created and owners assiged. Little bit of deduction and you will figure it out, should not be hard.
Open another database with the original SYSDBA user working and run CREATE USER [FOUND_USERNAME] PASSWORD 'masterkey' GRANT ADMIN ROLE;
Login to the required database


You need to connect with a different user than SYSDBA, and drop the role SYSDBA.
This can be done by:

The database owner.
Find the database owner with:
select distinct RDB$OWNER_NAME 
from RDB$RELATIONS 
where RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG = 1


The role owner.
Find the role owner with:
select RDB$OWNER_NAME
from RDB$ROLES
where RDB$ROLE_NAME = 'SYSDBA'


A user with the role RDB$ADMIN in that specific database if they specify that role when connecting.
Find members of RDB$ADMIN with:
select RDB$USER
from RDB$USER_PRIVILEGES
where RDB$PRIVILEGE = 'M'
and RDB$RELATION_NAME = 'RDB$ADMIN'



Above queries can be executed by any user, even unprivileged users. If needed you can create a user — with SYSDBA — by connecting to the employee example database, or any other database, and then connect to the database in question.
Find out the owner or a privileged user, create that user (or if it already exists, use or change its password), and then with any of those users, simply execute:
drop role SYSDBA;

(In case of RDB$ADMIN members, make sure to specify the role when connecting.)
If the owner of the database and role is SYSDBA, and there are no users with the RDB$ADMIN role, then you'll be in a bit of a bind, and I think the only way to fix it then is to use a hex editor, find the right occurrence of SYSDBA, and change it (e.g. to SYSDBB; use the same number of characters!). It is important that you change the right occurrence of SYSDBA, because if you change the wrong occurrence, I think you might break other privileges of SYSDBA.

I am sure there is another user with RDB$ADMIN but I am unable to find it. Is there a method to find it?
The queries you provide above assume I am connected to the database, but I can't connect therefore I can't execute them.

@Vega You should be able to connect with any user, except SYSDBA, to that database . Just create a user through a different database (e.g. employee), or using the gsec tool, and then connect to the database in question, execute the query, to find the right user with sufficient permissions, if necessary create it or reset its password, and then drop the role with that user.

And if there is a DB trigger that prevents arbitrary users from connecting, use the ISQL tool to connect with the -nodbtriggers commandline option.

"I think the only way to fix it then is to use a hex editor." Backup and restore with different owner using embedded engine can work as well. Just copy fbembed.dll to fbclient.dll to make gbak work with it.

@user13964273 That won't work if you don't have a user with sufficient privileges to read all tables (you won't be able to create a backup!).
